# Larger Silverlight Project Implementations

Tags: .net, silverlight, silverlight-4.0

As Silverlight applications become larger and larger, is it wise to break out an application into separate smaller applications by functional area, to keep the total xap file size lower?  Is download size a concern for any silverlight developers, or is it OK because of the way that it can be downloaded and cached on the client?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [Prism](http://compositewpf.codeplex.com/).  Keeping an eye on the size of the xap file is crucial.  As an end-user I'm not generally going to wait for something to load, I'll just move on to another site.  Prism will help because it allows you to "easily" load modules on demand.  This includes being able to load "modules" at app startup or in the background or a mix.

Answer (score 0):

I would say keeping each XAP small aids in the overall performance of the application. I have also implementation MEF in some areas of a large business application for dynamic loading of XAP files

[MEF](http://mef.codeplex.com/)

You are good to go with MEF in .Net 4 as its in the framework

Comment: In cases where nearly all the functionality is need up-front, any type of dynamic loading won't help (in fact it would prob hurt). No?

Comment: If you need the functionality up front then dynamic loading makes little sense and would likely result in some performance degradation. From my experience having the more abstracted implementation over the code, including the ViewModels using MVVM present more benifits than problems. Just my opinion...